# How to change submit value of form after used by AjaxForm

Tags: ajax, jquery, ajaxform

I am using AjaxForm extension to submit form with ajax as following

```
var options = 
        {
            url:'<?php echo site_url('user/ajaximage')?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:   function(data)
            {
                if(data.messagecode==1)
                {
                    $(".wrap label").hide();
                    $("#preview").html("<img src='"+data.content+"'class='preview'>");
                    $("#errormessagepic").hide();
                }
                else if(data.messagecode==0)
                {
                    $("#errormessagepic").html(data.content);
                    $("#preview").html('<img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/avatar_generic.png" />');        
                }
                //$('#SignupForm').resetForm();
                //$("#SignupForm").attr('action','<?php echo site_url('user/individualprofile')?>');
            } ,
        }; 
        $("#SignupForm").ajaxForm(options);
        $("#SignupForm").submit();
```

but after this ajax submission I want to resend form to another URL other than '' but it does not work. Any help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to post a form using ajax to two different urls. I dont know about your extension but i can tell you how to do this.

1- create a function and run this function when the user clicks on the submit
    <-input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="post_form()"-/>

2- Create the body of the function, this function will submit data to two urls

```
    function post_form(){

    // save the values in text boxes in variable

    var val1=$("#text1").val();
    var val2=$("#text2").val();

    var data={name:val1,age:val2};

    var url1="savedata.php";
    var url2="updatedata.php";

    $.post(url1,data, function(response){ 

    alert(response);

    // so when the form is submited to ur1 this callback function runs and here you can submit it to another url

    $.post(url1,data,function(response){alert(response)});

    });

    }

</script>
```